# Background task won't run on Pi but does on windows

Tags: background, daemon

I have written a program that sets up a daemon in python to count down some timers in the background that are interrogated in the main task and it works fine under windows but not on the actual required target which is a Pi.

I have the obligatory imports:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
```

and then declare the background function:

```
# Background Function called every 100ms to decrement button delay timers
def timer():
    while True:
        time.sleep(100/1000)

        for i in range (No_Of_Buttons):
            if(ButtonDelay[i] > 0):
                ButtonDelay[i] = ButtonDelay[i] - 1
```

and then in the post init phase I have:

```
daemon = Thread(target=timer, daemon=True, name='timer')
daemon.start()
```

and then the main program sets the delay values to other than zero and in doing so prevents other things from happening.

This all works great on my PC but fails on the Pi.

I put a print('Tick') statement in the daemon and under windows it prints 'tick' every 100 or so ms.
On the Pi I get nothing and the program behaviour is like what I would expect if the ButtonDelay[x] values weren't being zeroed over time.

In the main program if a button is pressed

```
    while(ButtonDelay[bcode] > 0):
        continue
   # Now do button stuff
```

so I would expect it to delay the rest of the button execution until the associated ButtonDelay[] is 0

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out why this wouldn't work. I had run an earlier version of the code that had flaws while I was sorting out how to do it, and it wasn't cleanly shut down.

A new boot with a clean slate and it worked.

I leave this here in the hope that someone will benefit.